# Specify PackageFlatten for content files in Nuget package using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to get content files in a C#.Net project that is being packed into a Nuget package to flatten the containing folders.  Based on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec) it seems that this is possible with the flatten attribute.

But I want to use the new MSBuild Nuget packaging built into VS2017.  Based on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets), I should be able to achieve the same thing with the `<PackageFlatten>` tag, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is a basic project file which demonstrates the problem.  I'm expecting the single content file under the folder hierarchy .\RemoveMe\ContentFile.txt to end up in the Nuget package under .\content\ContentFile.txt - i.e. without the folder RemoveMe.  But I still get this subfolder.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="RemoveMe\ContentFile.txt">
      <PackageFlatten>true</PackageFlatten>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Got the same result. It seems to me this may be a bug for the `PackageFlatten`, you can submit this to Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> Specify PackageFlatten for content files in Nuget package using Visual Studio 2017

It should be a issue about argument `flatten="true"` for me. According to the document [NuGet ContentFiles Demystified](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html)：

> flatten - Should the files be all delivered to the root folder of the project or should they keep the folder structure that they were packaged in. The default value is false, which indicates they should create (if necessary) and keep the same structure they have after the TFM folder in the pacakge.

So if we set this argument `flatten="true"` in the .nuspec file, then pack this .nuspec, install the generate nuget package to the project, the file should be  delivered to the root folder of the project. But after install this package to project, still got the that file in the sub-folder RemoveMe not in the root folder.

I also test other arguments `buildAction="content" copyToOutput="false"`, both of them works fine.

So it should be a issue for the argument `flatten="true"`, I submit [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6213), you can track this issue.